# Internet explorer 10/11 focus and google maps scroll-zoom

Tags: javascript, google-maps, focus

If you open [maps.google.com](http://maps.google.com) in internet explorer 10/11 on windows 7,

Click on IE url bar, and then

Click on the maps itself,

You can only move the map, NOT zoom it using your mouse wheel.

Once area outside the map is clicked, and you go back to your map, you can move and ZOOM using your mouse wheel.

What is happening here ?

I have the same issue with my web application,

and i can fix it on IE9 (not 10/11) by re-focusing on maps area ( $('#map'.focus() )
if i detect a mousemove event over the map.

Ideas?

Comment: For the issue with the maps.google.com application, I'd raise an issue using the in app "Report a Problem" link. This work flow supplies required context to the app team so they can debug the problem. For the issue with the JS API, please reduce your problem to the most minimal sample that demonstrates the issue, and then file a bug on https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/